# How to set root public folder permissions in Exchange 2010

Tags: permissions, exchange-2010, public-folders

I am currently running Exchange Server 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I have a user that I would like to be able to create/delete public folders in the root public folder.

How do I give this user permission to do this?

So far I have tried adding the user to the Public Folder Management, Domain Admins, and Administrators groups, and running the following scripts in the powershell:

```
Add-PublicFolderAdministrativePermission -Identity "\" -User "Username" -AccessRights AllExtendedRights -InheritanceType SelfAndChildren
```

This appears to have done something, but the user still cannot create public folders in the root public folder.

```
 AddUsersToPFRecursive.ps1 -toppublicfolder \ -User "Username" -Permissions Owner
```

This gives me an access denied error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Exchange user name instead of the domain login name. By Default this is the First Name plus the Last name. For example, use "John Smith" instead of "jsmith". So, the command would be:

```
AddUsersToPFRecursive.ps1 -toppublicfolder \ -User "FirstName LastName" -Permissions Owner
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633461.aspx

Especially the comparison `Administrator access rights differences` in section `Administrator Access Rights`. Only users in group `Public Folder Management role group` can create top-level public folders.

Comment: Yea, I've tried adding the user to that group, but it still doesn't work...